# searchable dropdown up and down arrows are not working in list using angularJS

Tags: angularjs

[image]I am getting list from angularJS.when am click input textfield that list will be displaying and in 0 index level put a filter box.In this scenario up and down arrow keys functionality not working.

```
 <div class="dropdown">
        <inputclass="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" value = "{{subapplication}}" id="subapplicationid"  ng-model="subapplication"  ng-class="{'errorhilight': !isApplicationSelected}">
         <span class="caret"></span>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
            <li><input type="text" placeholder="search..." ng-model="searchString"></li>
            <li ng-repeat="subapp in subapplicationList | filter:searchString" ><a href="#" ng-click="getSubApplicationDetails(subapp)">{{subapp.ID}}-{{subapp.DESCRIPCION}}</a></li>
         </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: do you want increment or decrement number ? input type="number" means you can do.

Comment: can you create chat box

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141643/angularjs-discussion

Comment: my requirement is when click up and down arrows click the index value only increment,but input type="number" is serching the list.

Comment: sorry I dont have enough reputation,So can't able to get chat box

Comment: Add screen shot

Comment: refer this https://plnkr.co/edit/lMy3nrVwXHANHpk9w6rR?p=preview

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#typeahead

Comment: In the examples are good,But the requirement look like as screen shot only